# Changing to right to left wordpress theme css

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, right-to-left

I have a wordpress theme containing style.css & rtl.css, beside other theme files.
I want to change the theme to Right to Left for Arabic. What should I do? Use @import in style.css? Or replacing the text in style.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To active the Right to Left (RTL) in wordpress you should define the language to Arabic first by edit the line in wp-config.php
just add ar between the '' to be 'ar'

```
define( 'WPLANG', 'ar' );
```

then, go to http://ar.wordpress.org and download the package, extract/unzip and upload the folder
/wp-content/languages to your wordpress /wp-content
refresh your blog and it should changed automatically to arabic

> PS: changing the WPLANG will effect admin menus and everything in the
>   template will changes to the language matches **ar.po** (in /languages folder if it translated by the theme or plugin.

please note that the language file must match the WPLANG name, in this case WPLANG set to ar so the .po file must be ar.po.

Answer (score 2):

The Wordpress support has step by step instructions on how to make the wordpress theme RTL:

[RTL Language Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support)

There's also a plugin that shows how the theme will look like in RTL:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rtl-tester/

Answer (score 1):

In your `header.php` file you'll have a line similar to:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Replace it with:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You're replacing the default stylesheet with the right-to-left one.

Comment: i didn't find any line contain style.css or rtl.css in header.php

Comment: And none containing `bloginfo('stylesheet_url');`? It should be in there somewhere. Take a look at the interpreted source-code in a browser and check where the link is made.

Comment: i've searched in all theme files i found this lines http://pastebin.com/mj6DjEea `* Includes the post editor stylesheet.
 */
if( ! function_exists( 'standard_add_theme_editor_style' ) ) { 
 function standard_add_theme_editor_style() {
  
  add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style.css' );
  
  $options = get_option( 'standard_theme_presentation_options' );
  if( 'full_width_layout' == $options['layout'] ) {
   add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style-full.css' );
  } // end if
 
 } // end standard_add_theme_editor_style
 add_action( 'init', 'standard_add_theme_editor_style' );
} // end if`

Comment: This doesn't look like the right code, you need to search for where `style.css` is being included. Or as I said above, check for the `bloginfo('stylesheet_url');` call.

Comment: i spent long time to review file by file looking for bloginfo connect or style.css, didn't find any, and when i use plugin called 'RTL tester' its work very well for me (admin view) only, i would like to make it visible for viewers also

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Settings => General in your WordPress dashboard and select the preferred “Site language” – don’t forget to hit the “Save Changes” button. WordPress detects whether your chosen language is a RTL language and when your WordPress theme supports RTL, the rtl.css stylesheet is loaded automatically and your website will be displayed in RTL. That’s it.

for more information visit this page: [How to enable RTL for your WordPress website?](https://www.mhthemes.com/support/enable-rtl-language-support-wordpress/)